# How can I read a dictionary from database without it being turned into a string by django?

Tags: django

My database contains a dictionary.  When I read the dictionary from the database and try to do something with it it fails because the dictionary has been automatically converted into a string. Any way to avoid Django turning the dict into a string?

[image: JSON stored in database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use simplejson.loads() and simplejson.dumps() to deserialize and serialize the dictionary. It is a bit more work, but it ensures that you are not dependent on database.

Answer (score 0):

There are options for MySQL and Postgres but I don't think there's an equivalent for sqlite.

For MySQL JSONField: https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html

Similarly for Postgres:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

There's built in support to query the contents of the fields which is pretty neat. The docs show examples.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue with help from the responses I got here.

When capturing and saving the JSON from the webhook (as that's where the JSON is coming from in my project), I had to do the strange step of serialising and deserialising the JSON before saving it to my database. This process got rid of all the \r and \t charactors which are passed by request.body but make the JSON invalid:

```
t = Transaction(data=json.dumps(json.loads(request.body)))
t.save()
```

To load the JSON from database into a python dictionary that I can then use in my code I used json.loads:

```
data = json.loads(t.data)
```